# integration-inbound-gateway configured with concurrent consumer

Tags: spring, duplicates, jms, spring-integration, message-queue

This is our gateway configuration

```
    <int-jms:inbound-gateway
    request-destination-name="co.jms.local.InternalDispatcher"
    request-channel="dispatch" destination-        resolver="serviceJmsDestinationResolver"
    connection-factory="serviceConnectionFactory" transaction-manager="transactionManager"
    receive-timeout="60000" error-channel="errorLoggingChannel" concurrent-consumers="5"  />
```

since the gateway is capable of handling concurrent client. a long processing message is not removed from the queue and its handled by the redeliverymessage and send back to the queue for processing. thus resulting in duplicate processing of the message and exception in the db transaction. 
as a workaround we have tried to increase the redelivery delay by 40 mins for heavy processing and this seems to be working but i don't find this workaround a very positive one. 
Can someone suggest what should be possible fix. 
spring-integration-jms.4.1.0/4.1.1 has the same result.

Comment: I am not familiar with "redelivery delay" - if the broker can redeliver an in-process message, that's a bit weird (and outside of the JMS spec AFAIK). Which JMS provider are you using? However 40 minutes is a long time to keep a message open - liable to cause problems with network glitches etc. Perhaps it would be better to move in-process requests to a different queue.

Comment: we are using weblogic 12c.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what "redelivery delay" you are talking about but I seriously doubt Websphere MQ would redeliver an in-process message. My best guess is some network glitch caused the session to close (requeuing the message), which makes it a candidate for redelivery.

As I said in my comment, holding an un-acked message in process for a long duration is simply asking for trouble.

You should come up with some other architecture so you can ack the message in a reasonably short time (e.g. move it to an in-process DB table or similar). Or, perhaps messaging is just not the right solution for your problem.

Comment: After investigation it was found that there was problematic code because of which the message processing was taking time and hence we were getting redelivery of the message.